# Adding css file to dom html in Angularjs 2

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a variable in component file which stores the css file.

```
var x = '.someClass { background: pink; } .someClass1 { background: purple; }'
```

How can I paste this in style tag to dom.

I tried this.

```
this.globalStyles= this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(x);

<style [style]='globalStyles'></style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really apply this row:

```
'.someClass { background: pink; } .someClass1 { background: purple; }'
```

It will be invalid. Here you trying to define classes, looks like it should be in CSS.

Just use the basic JS syntax:

```
document.getElementById('id').setAttribute('style', 'background: pink; background: purple');
```

Angular will understand it (but i have no idea, why do you want to apply `background` property twice).

And in your component:

```
import {Component, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
...
export class YourComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    document.getElementById('id').setAttribute('style', 'background: pink; background: purple');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first, please notice that you are mixing two different concepts. styles and classes are not the same. In your case you have:

```
var x = '.someClass { background: pink; } .someClass1 { background: purple; }'
```

Here x is containing the definition for 2 classes. According to my experience, you should declare those classes inside of a .css or .scss or .less file, for instance inside of the your_component_name.scss file which will contain your classes instead of this x variable.

After, you would be able use those classes in your html tags like this:

```
<some-element [ngClass]="'someClass someClass1'"></some-element>
```

For more info read the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass). Hope it helps!!